# "from A import B.C" in Python?

Tags: python, attributes, python-import

In Python, it is possible to import dotted submodules explicitly:

```
import os.path
```

makes `os.path` available.

Now, is there a simple way to do the same thing for sub-submodules? The following code (which does not work) illustrates what I am looking for:

```
from A import B.C
from A import B.D
```

(`from A import B` does *not* import `B.C` and `B.D`, for the module `A.B` that I need to use). I would like to do this because:

- I prefer to not pollute the main namespace with `C` and `D` (`from A.B import C, D`) because they do not have very specific names.
- I would like to keep the sub-submodules inside their `B` namespace (for the same reason).

One solution is to do:

```
from A import B
from A.B import C, D
del C, D
```

which loads and defines `B.C` and `B.D`. However, this is (1) quite unusual, (2) somewhat obscure (side effect of defining `B.C` and `B.D`) and (3) maybe with a result that's not guaranteed (will `B.C` and `B.D` always be defined with this code?).

Is this method of putting only `B.C` and `B.D` (and `B`) in the namespace acceptable? is there a better method? maybe it actually best to find some legible compromise like `from A.B import C as B_C, D as B_D`?

While I am stuck with Python 2.6 (no importlib module…), for this problem, I am also curious about any modern solution.

Comment: Why not `import A` and use `A.B.C` and `A.B.D`?

Comment: Yes, but `A` is in practice quite a long name and the calls are numerous, so I'd like to find a compromise between legibility and convenience, especially since the name `B` is in my case quite specific . Using `B.C` and `B.D` would be a nice compromise.

Comment: @JayanthKoushik: Furthermore, `A.B` is not imported by `import A`, so this does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`importlib` can help here

```
import importlib
from A import B
importlib.import_module('A.B.C')
importlib.import_module('A.B.D')
# Now you can use B.C & B.D
```

On Python2.6 you should be able to

```
from A import B
import A.B.C
import A.B.D
del A
```

Comment: While it does not work in my case (Python 2.6), it's cleaner than my `from A import B; from A.B import C; del C` (which I'm not sure is guaranteed to work, i.e. to always make `B.C` available).

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if Python the less elegant `from A import B; from A.B import C, D; del C, D` guarantees that `B.C` and `B.D` are created (and kept around)? A reference would be much appreciated, if you have any! Similarly, a reference showing that `import A.B.C` makes `B.C` available would be great!

Answer (score 2):

For the intent of `from A import B.C`, I would suggest doing this:

```
from A.B import C as B_C
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the cleanest ways is to do what Jayanth mentioned. If `A` is a long name then you can rename using the 'as' keyword

```
import A as X
```

Comment: This is definitely not an answer to the question…

Comment: This answer was only provided as an improvement to Jayanth's comment. Down voting such a suggestion can certainly not be a civil practice. The only reason I did not post a comment was simply because I did not have enough reps to post it as a comment. 

As a matter of fact @vonPetrushev answer which is upvoted is very similar to my answer.

Comment: Sorry, I realize now that I had missed the "do what Jayanth mentioned" part. I removed my downvote (I still understand that downvoting an answer that's not an answer is appropriate, since answers can even be flagged if they fail this test—but this does not apply here). If you flesh out your answer and make it more explicit and self-contained, I will consider upvoting it, because the idea is good.